# Validate XHTML in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, validation, jsf, xhtml

I am trying to validate my jsf xhtml source file in Eclipse. When I navigate to the file in the project Explorer, and right-click, I select the "validate" option. I am assuming this is what I would be looking for in the menu options present. When I click "validate", I get "The validation completed with no errors or warnings". To test that the validation was running correctly, I deleted closing tags, saved the file, and re-ran. I still received the same successful validation window.

Am I picking the incorrect menu option? Does something else need to be set up? How do you properly validate xhtml using Eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you do not have (X)HTML editor plugin in Eclipse. You can try downloading them and installing it to your Eclipse. Few links are [link1](http://www.easyeclipse.org/site/plugins/eclipsetidy.html), [link2](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/community/tutorials/XMLValidation/XMLValidationTutorial.html) and [link3](http://colorer.sourceforge.net/)

For automatically invoking the Validator during Builds,

To run validation as part of building, the Validation Builder must be set on the project and the desired validators enabled. To ensure that the builder is set onto the project, open the Properties dialog for the project and go to the Validation property page. If the Add Validation Builder to project checkbox is present, enable it. Then, enable the Build checkbox for the desired validators, overriding the main validation preferences if necessary.

[image]

Comment: OP incorrectly overgeneralized "Facelets" as "XHTML". Facelets is XHTML, but XHTML is not Facelets. None of those plugins are applicable on Facelets.